# Continuous functions with $f^2(x)=g^2(x)\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f,g:[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be continuous functions with $f^2(x)=g^2(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Show $f=g$ or $f=-g$ on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Consider the function 
$$
h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
and apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(x)=f(x)+g(x), j(x) = f(x)-g(x)$. The hypotheses show that
$h(x)j(x) = f^2(x)-g(x)^2 = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Also, $h,j$ are continuous,
and for all $x$ we have $h(x) \neq 0$ or $j(x) \neq 0$ (otherwise
$f(x)=g(x) = 0$).

Suppose $h(a) = 0$. The set $Z=\{x| h(x) = 0 \}$ is closed since $h$
is continuous, and $a \in Z$ so it is non empty. If $x \in Z$, then
$j(x) \neq 0$ and since $j(y) \neq 0$ in some neighbourhood of $x$
we see that $Z$ is open and so connected. Hence $Z=[a,b]$ and $f=-g$.

If $j(a) = 0$ a similar analysis applies and $f=g$.

**Alternative**:

Since $f$ is continuous and non zero, $f$ does not change sign on $[a,b]$. Similarly for $g$.

Let $\sigma_f, \sigma_g$ be the signs of $f,g$ respectively, then
$f(x) = \sigma_f \sqrt{f^2(x)}, g(x) = \sigma_g \sqrt{g^2(x)}$ from
which it follows that $f(x) = { \sigma_f \over \sigma_g} g(x)$ for all $x$
and since ${ \sigma_f \over \sigma_g} = \pm 1$ we have the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_1=\{x\in [a,b]: f(x)=g(x)\}$, $V_1=\{x\in [a,b]: f(x)\neq g(x)\}$

Let $U_2=\{x\in [a,b]: f(x)=-g(x)\}$, $V_2=\{x\in [a,b]: f(x)\neq -g(x)\}$

Remark that $V_1=U_2$ and $U_1=V_2$. If $V_1$ is not empty, then $V_1$ is $[a,b]$ since $V_1$ is open and $U_2$ is closed.

If $V_2$ is not empty, then $V_2$ is $[a,b]$ since $V_2$ is open and $U_1$ is closed.